# How to validate uniqueness for a certain time period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to validate that a value is unique but only for the previous week.

The rails guide gives the following example to add a condition:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :title, conditions: -> { where.not(status: 'archived') }
```

I tried to modify it so that it only checks the last 7 days:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :title, conditions: -> { where(created_at: 7.days.ago..DateTime.now) }
```

It is still checking all records and not just the last 7 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways could be:

```
validate :validate_within_a_week

private

  def validate_within_a_week
    if ModelName.exists?(title: self.title, created_at: 7.days.ago..DateTime.now)
      errors.add(:title, "already exists.")
    end
  end
```

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Best way to say thanks is to accept an answer. ;)

Comment: It is more efficient to use the `exists?` method instead of loading a bulk of records and then check if you have loaded any: `ModelName.exists?(title: ..., created_at:...)`.